# How to show a large string using mPDF generator in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, mpdf

I am using the mPDF library for PHP to generate a PDF in Unicode (bangla font). For this I am using the `MultiCell()` function of the mPDF library to print something. It will work for single-line printing but when I insert a large string, the browser says: "Failed to load PDF document". My code is given below:

```
<?php 
    if(!empty($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $noticeby = $_POST['noticeby']; 
    }

    include("mpdf/mpdf.php");

    $mpdf = new mPDF('','A4',16,'nikosh');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('');
    $text = 'তারিখ: '.$date;

    $mpdf->MultiCell(100,10,'',0,'L',0);
    $mpdf->MultiCell(180,10,$text,0,'L',1);
    $text = ' যে  ল্যাব ফাইনাল পরীক্ষায় অবশ্যই প্রবেশপত্র নিয়ে আসতে হবে। প্রবেশপ';//okay with this length but when i try to add rest, then the problem creates everytime//'এতদ্বারা সিএসই বিভাগের সকল নিয়মিত ও অনিয়মিত সেমিস্টারের ছাত্র';
    $mpdf->MultiCell(180,10,$text,0,'L',0);

    $mpdf->Output('');

    exit;
?>
```

Comment: You could convert the text to utf-8 encoding before passing it to mPDF, using any one of the PHP functions: utf8_encode, iconv or mb_convert_encoding. https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/input-encoding.html

Comment: @DanielO. the string is already converted in utf-8 but it doesn't help

Comment: Your code works on my computer, also with the long string. Try this: http://jobnstudy.blogspot.de/2016/10/how-to-write-bengali-bangla-unicode-pdf.html

Comment: Is the font that you're using a utf-8 font?

Comment: @DanielO. is the following code runs swiftly on your computer... http://ideone.com/LOQ7oj

Comment: @MarkBaker yes.. i'm using utf-8 font

Answer (score 0):

Nikosh is a unicode font and must be configured in mpdf.

Just follow this tutorial: http://jobnstudy.blogspot.de/2016/10/how-to-write-bengali-bangla-unicode-pdf.html

Add this configuration to config_fonts.php.

```
$this->fontdata = array(    
    /* Bangla Nikosh */
    "nikosh" => array(
        'R' => "Nikosh.ttf",
        'useOTL' => 0xFF,
    ),
```

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtEQG.jpg

Comment: I have already done all this a lot before... The same code your device is running, can't run by my device.... That's the problem... don't know whether it is a technical issue or not...by the way, thanks :)